# Генерация рандом числа PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Хочу сделать что-то наподобие рандома для бонуса.

У меня есть два кода и два окна.

В первом окне при нажатии на `pushButton` открывается окно, где можно будет получить бонусные поинты.

Хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии на втором окне на кнопку приложение генерировало число от одного до 50 (чаще всего числа должны быть: 1, 2, 3, 4 и изредка больше.

И потом это рандом число должно отобразиться в `splash`,
а потом уже на главном окне количество поинтов написанных в `label` должно прибавиться в зависимости сколько поинтов я получил в бонусе.

**ggt.png**:

[image: splash]

**rry.png**:

[image: splash]

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from punkti import PointApp

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(520, 588)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 521, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(60)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваши пункты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Не хватает пунктов?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КЛИКАЙ"))

class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked1)     
        self.exampleApp_2 = PointApp() 

    def onClicked1(self):
            self.exampleApp_2.show()

    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())   

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**punkti.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(520, 588)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 400, 251, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 521, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(29)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Получить пункты"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Бесплатные пункты"))

class PointApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()       
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)    # +                  
        self.pressing = False        # +


# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updtTime)
        self.testTimeDisplay = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setFixedSize(0.1, 0.1)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setSegmentStyle(QtWidgets.QLCDNumber.Filled)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setDigitCount(8)

        self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(1) 
        self.fl = True
        self.sec = ...
        self.updtTime()
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def onClicked(self):
        if self.fl:
            self.BonusGet()
            self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*60*60*24)       # 1 мин = 60 сек
            # self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*60*60*24) # раз в 24 часа
            self.fl = False
            self.sec = 0
        else:
            self.flashSplash()

    def updtTime(self):
        currentTime = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.testTimeDisplay.display(currentTime)

        # QDateTime::secsTo(const QDateTime &other) const
        # Возвращает количество секунд от этой даты до другой даты. 
        # Если другой datetime раньше, чем this date, возвращаемое значение будет отрицательным.

        self.sec = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().secsTo(self.dt)
        if self.sec <= 0:
            self.fl = True


    def flashSplash(self):
        # Обязательно сохраните ссылку на SplashScreen иначе это будет мусор
        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('rry.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)  # width()
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(
            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Кнопка будет доступна через {} секунд</h2>'.format(self.sec), 
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)# | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)    

        # Закройте SplashScreen через 5 секунды (5000 мс)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)

    def BonusGet(self):
               # Обязательно сохраните ссылку на SplashScreen иначе это будет мусор
        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('ggt.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)  # width()
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(
            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Вы получили ??????????? пунктов</h2>'.format(self.sec), 
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)# | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)    

        # Закройте SplashScreen через 5 секунды (5000 мс)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)

# + vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PointApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: random.randint(a, b) чем-то не подходит?

Comment: Нужен полный пример как это все вывести

Comment: у вас используется `self.splash.showMessage()`, разве не оно?

Comment: А вот теперь как это вывести в лабел на главном окне и в сплеш для меня остаётся загадкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проследите за `self.bonus_point`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import random                                                         # +++

#from punkti import PointApp
class Ui_MainWindow_PointApp(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(520, 588)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 400, 251, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 521, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(29)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Получить пункты"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Бесплатные пункты"))

class PointApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_PointApp):
    def __init__(self, parent):                                         # + parent
        super().__init__()       
        self.setupUi(self)
# +++        
        self.parent = parent                                            # + parent

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)                      
        self.pressing = False        
# +++        
        self.bonus_point = 0                                             # +++ <---

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updtTime)
        self.testTimeDisplay = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setFixedSize(0.1, 0.1)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setSegmentStyle(QtWidgets.QLCDNumber.Filled)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setDigitCount(8)

        self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(1) 
        self.fl = True
        self.sec = ...
        self.updtTime()
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def onClicked(self):
        if self.fl:
# +++
            self.bonus_point = random.randint(1, 5)

            self.BonusGet()
            self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*6 ) #0*60*24)       # 1 мин = 60 сек
            # self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*60*60*24) # раз в 24 часа

            self.fl = False
            self.sec = 0
        else:
            self.flashSplash()

    def updtTime(self):
        currentTime = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.testTimeDisplay.display(currentTime)

        # QDateTime::secsTo(const QDateTime &other) const
        # Возвращает количество секунд от этой даты до другой даты. 
        # Если другой datetime раньше, чем this date, возвращаемое значение будет отрицательным.

        self.sec = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().secsTo(self.dt)
        if self.sec <= 0:
            self.fl = True


    def flashSplash(self):
        # Обязательно сохраните ссылку на SplashScreen иначе это будет мусор
        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('rry.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)  # width()
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(
            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Кнопка будет доступна через {} секунд</h2>'.format(self.sec), 
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)# | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)    

        # Закройте SplashScreen через 5 секунды (5000 мс)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)

    def BonusGet(self):
               # Обязательно сохраните ссылку на SplashScreen иначе это будет мусор
        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('ggt.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)  # width()
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(

#            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Вы получили ??????????? пунктов</h2>'.format(self.sec), 
# +++
            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Вы получили {} пунктов</h2>'.format(self.bonus_point), 

            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)# | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)    

        # Закройте SplashScreen через 5 секунды (5000 мс)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)
# +++        
        self.parent.label_2.setNum(int(self.parent.label_2.text()) + self.bonus_point)



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(520, 588)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 521, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(60)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваши пункты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Не хватает пунктов?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КЛИКАЙ"))

class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked1)     
        self.exampleApp_2 = PointApp(self)                         # self 

    def onClicked1(self):
            self.exampleApp_2.show()

    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())   

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> но вот только маленький вопрос, можно ли сделать чтоб рандом генерировал числа с точками например 1.51, 3.24?

Можно, смотрите комментарии `# float`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import random                                                         # +++

#from punkti import PointApp
class Ui_MainWindow_PointApp(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(520, 588)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 400, 251, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 521, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(29)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Получить пункты"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Бесплатные пункты"))

class PointApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_PointApp):
    def __init__(self, parent):                                         # + parent
        super().__init__()       
        self.setupUi(self)
# +++        
        self.parent = parent                                            # + parent

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)                      
        self.pressing = False        
# +++        
        self.bonus_point = 0                                             # +++ <---

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updtTime)
        self.testTimeDisplay = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setFixedSize(0.1, 0.1)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setSegmentStyle(QtWidgets.QLCDNumber.Filled)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setDigitCount(8)

        self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(1) 
        self.fl = True
        self.sec = ...
        self.updtTime()
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def onClicked(self):
        if self.fl:
# +++
#            self.bonus_point = random.randint(1, 5)
            self.bonus_point = random.uniform(1, 5.5)                   # float

            self.BonusGet()
            self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*6 ) #0*60*24)       # 1 мин = 60 сек
            # self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*60*60*24) # раз в 24 часа

            self.fl = False
            self.sec = 0
        else:
            self.flashSplash()

    def updtTime(self):
        currentTime = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.testTimeDisplay.display(currentTime)

        # QDateTime::secsTo(const QDateTime &other) const
        # Возвращает количество секунд от этой даты до другой даты. 
        # Если другой datetime раньше, чем this date, возвращаемое значение будет отрицательным.

        self.sec = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().secsTo(self.dt)
        if self.sec <= 0:
            self.fl = True


    def flashSplash(self):
        # Обязательно сохраните ссылку на SplashScreen иначе это будет мусор
        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('rry.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)  # width()
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(
            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Кнопка будет доступна через {} секунд</h2>'.format(self.sec), 
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)# | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)    

        # Закройте SplashScreen через 5 секунды (5000 мс)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)

    def BonusGet(self):
               # Обязательно сохраните ссылку на SplashScreen иначе это будет мусор
        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('ggt.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)  # width()
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(

#            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Вы получили ??????????? пунктов</h2>'.format(self.sec), 
# +++
            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Вы получили {:.2f} пунктов</h2>'.format(self.bonus_point), 

            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)# | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)    

        # Закройте SplashScreen через 5 секунды (5000 мс)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)
# +++        
#        self.parent.label_2.setNum(int(self.parent.label_2.text()) + self.bonus_point)
        self.parent.label_2.setText(
            str(round(float(self.parent.label_2.text()) + self.bonus_point, 2)))   # float



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(520, 588)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 521, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(60)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваши пункты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Не хватает пунктов?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КЛИКАЙ"))

class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked1)     
        self.exampleApp_2 = PointApp(self)                         # self 

    def onClicked1(self):
            self.exampleApp_2.show()

    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())   

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @imapw_ является ли данный ответ для вас полезным ?

Comment: да, все что надо было правильно работает

Comment: но вот только маленький вопрос, можно ли сделать чтоб рандом генерировал числа с точками например 1.51, 3.24?

Comment: @imapw_ можно добавить к имеющемуся результату добавить randint(0,100)/100

Comment: @imapw_ я добавил ответ, с вас галочка в верхнем левом углу моего ответа `Ответ полезен`

Answer (score 1):

Строки, которые изменены отмечены комментарием `# добалена строка`

main.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from punkti import PointApp

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(520, 588)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 521, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(60)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваши пункты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Не хватает пунктов?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КЛИКАЙ"))

class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked1)
        self.exampleApp_2 = PointApp()

    def onClicked1(self):
            self.exampleApp_2.show()
            self.label_2.setText(f"{self.exampleApp_2.bonuses}")   # добалена строка

    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

punkti.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from random import randint

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(520, 588)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 400, 251, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 521, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(29)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Получить пункты"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Бесплатные пункты"))

class PointApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.bonuses=randint(1,50)  # добалена строка
        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)    # +
        self.pressing = False        # +


# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updtTime)
        self.testTimeDisplay = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setFixedSize(0.1, 0.1)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setSegmentStyle(QtWidgets.QLCDNumber.Filled)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setDigitCount(8)

        self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(1)
        self.fl = True
        self.sec = ...
        self.updtTime()
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def onClicked(self):
        if self.fl:
            self.BonusGet()
            self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*60*60*24)       # 1 мин = 60 сек
            # self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*60*60*24) # раз в 24 часа
            self.fl = False
            self.sec = 0
        else:
            self.flashSplash()

    def updtTime(self):
        currentTime = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.testTimeDisplay.display(currentTime)

        # QDateTime::secsTo(const QDateTime &other) const
        # Возвращает количество секунд от этой даты до другой даты.
        # Если другой datetime раньше, чем this date, возвращаемое значение будет отрицательным.

        self.sec = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().secsTo(self.dt)
        if self.sec <= 0:
            self.fl = True


    def flashSplash(self):
        # Обязательно сохраните ссылку на SplashScreen иначе это будет мусор
        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('rry.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)  # width()
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(
            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Кнопка будет доступна через {} секунд</h2>'.format(self.sec),
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)# | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)

        # Закройте SplashScreen через 5 секунды (5000 мс)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)

    def BonusGet(self):
               # Обязательно сохраните ссылку на SplashScreen иначе это будет мусор
        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('ggt.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)  # width()
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(
            f'<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Вы получили {self.bonuses} пунктов</h2>',   # добалена строка
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)# | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)

        # Закройте SplashScreen через 5 секунды (5000 мс)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)

# + vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PointApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```